# Controls disappear after pressing the Edit link

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid, which is filled with data after a button is pressed.

It has columns for every day of a certain month:

[image: Image 1]

When the user presses the Edit button, I want the labels (showing text `dayLabelText`) to be replaced by controls for entering data of a particular value for that day of the month.

But when I press the Edit button, all the controls disappear:

[image: Image 2]

When I press the Cancel button, nothing changes.

[image: Image 3]

How should I modify the code shown below in order to fix this bug (when I press Edit, the dropdown lists should be shown, when I press Cancel - the text fields) ?

***.aspx file:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="plan.aspx.cs" Inherits="plan" 
    EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"  %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">

    [...]

    <asp:GridView 
        ID="dailyPlanGrid" 
        runat="server" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="dailyPlanGrid_RowCancelingEdit" 
        OnRowEditing="dailyPlanGrid_RowEditing"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="dailyPlanGrid_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"> 
                <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbkUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton> 
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton> 
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="titleLabelEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="titleLabelItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
 </asp:Content>
```

**.aspx.cs file:**

```
public partial class plan : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [...]

    private void UpdateGrid(int year, int month, string userName, bool updateTableCall = false)
    {
        [...]

        DisplaySelectedPlan(year, month, userName, updateTableCall);
    }

    private void DisplaySelectedPlan(int year, int month, string userName, bool updateTableCall = false)
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        DataColumn titleColumn = new DataColumn();

        titleColumn.ColumnName = "Title";
        titleColumn.Caption = "";

        data.Columns.Add(titleColumn);

        INumberOfDaysInMonthCalculator numberOfDaysInMonthCalculator = new NumberOfDaysInMonthCalculator();        

        int daysInMonth = numberOfDaysInMonthCalculator.GetNumberOfDays(year, month);

        if (updateTableCall)
        {
            AddDayColumns(daysInMonth);
        }

        var row = data.NewRow();
        row["Title"] = "Вид";
        data.Rows.Add(row);

        Database.Instance.Open();

        IDailyWorkingTimesReader dailyWorkingTimesReader = new DailyWorkingTimesReader(Database.Instance.SqlCommandFactory);

        dailyWorkingTimesReader.ReadData(year, month, userName);

        IDictionary<int, DateTime> startTimesByDay = dailyWorkingTimesReader.GetStartTimes();
        IDictionary<int, DateTime> endTimesByDay = dailyWorkingTimesReader.GetEndTimes();

        AddStartRow(data, daysInMonth, startTimesByDay);
        AddEndRow(data, daysInMonth, endTimesByDay);

        var holidayRow = data.NewRow();
        holidayRow["Title"] = "Госудаственный праздник";
        data.Rows.Add(holidayRow);

        var preHolidayRow = data.NewRow();
        preHolidayRow["Title"] = "Предпраздничный день";
        data.Rows.Add(preHolidayRow);

        dailyPlanGrid.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;

        dailyPlanGrid.DataSource = data;
        dailyPlanGrid.DataBind();
    }

    private void AddDayColumns(int daysInMonth)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
        {
            TemplateField dayColumn = new TemplateField();

            dayColumn.HeaderText = "" + i;
            dayColumn.EditItemTemplate = new DayEditItemTemplate(i);
            dayColumn.ItemTemplate = new DayItemTemplate(i);

            dailyPlanGrid.Columns.Add(dayColumn);
        }

    }

    private static void AddEndRow(DataTable data, int daysInMonth, IDictionary<int, DateTime> endTimesByDay)
    {
        var endRow = data.NewRow();
        endRow["Title"] = "Конец";

        FillTimeColumns(daysInMonth, endRow, endTimesByDay);

        data.Rows.Add(endRow);
    }

    private static void AddStartRow(DataTable data, int daysInMonth, IDictionary<int, DateTime> startTimesByDay)
    {
        var startRow = data.NewRow();
        startRow["Title"] = "Начало";

        FillTimeColumns(daysInMonth, startRow, startTimesByDay);
        data.Rows.Add(startRow);
    }

    private static void FillTimeColumns(int daysInMonth, DataRow row, IDictionary<int, DateTime> timesByDay)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
        {
            if (timesByDay.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                row["Day" + i] = timesByDay[i];
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreatePlanForSelectedEmployeeAndMonth(int year, int month, string userName)
    {
        IDailyPlanCreator dailyPlanCreator = new DailyPlanCreator(Database.Instance.SqlCommandFactory, 
            new NumberOfDaysInMonthCalculator());
        Database.Instance.Open();
        dailyPlanCreator.CreateDailyPlan(year, month, userName);
    }
    protected void updateTableButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Here the grid is initialized (after the user presses some button)

        DataTable dataTable = monthList.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[monthList.SelectedIndex] as DataRow;
        IUserNameExtractor userNameExtractor = new UserNameExtractor();

        UpdateGrid((int)row["year"], (int)row["month"], userNameExtractor.ExtractUserNameWithoutDomain(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name), true);
    }
    protected void dailyPlanGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        dailyPlanGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        DataTable dataTable = monthList.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[monthList.SelectedIndex] as DataRow;
        IUserNameExtractor userNameExtractor = new UserNameExtractor();

        UpdateGrid((int)row["year"], (int)row["month"], userNameExtractor.ExtractUserNameWithoutDomain(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name));
    }
    protected void dailyPlanGrid_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        dailyPlanGrid.EditIndex = -1;

        DataTable dataTable = monthList.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[monthList.SelectedIndex] as DataRow;
        IUserNameExtractor userNameExtractor = new UserNameExtractor();

        UpdateGrid((int)row["year"], (int)row["month"], userNameExtractor.ExtractUserNameWithoutDomain(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name));
    }
    protected void dailyPlanGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) && (dailyPlanGrid.EditIndex > -1))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = monthList.DataSource as DataTable;
            DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[monthList.SelectedIndex] as DataRow;

            int year = (int)row["year"];
            int month = (int)row["month"];

            INumberOfDaysInMonthCalculator numberOfDaysInMonthCalculator = new NumberOfDaysInMonthCalculator();        

            int daysInMonth = numberOfDaysInMonthCalculator.GetNumberOfDays(year, month);


            if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
            {
                // Type
                for (int i=1; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
                {
                    DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList) e.Row.FindControl("dayDropDownList" + i);

                    if (dropDownList != null)
                    {
                        dropDownList.Items.Clear();

                        dropDownList.Items.Add("item1");
                        dropDownList.Items.Add("item2");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowIndex == 1)
            {
                // Start time of the business day
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowIndex == 2)
            {
                // End time of the business day
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowIndex == 3)
            {
                // Holiday
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowIndex == 4)
            {
                // Pre-holiday
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the columns for all days are added programmatically. It must be done in this way because

1. the customer wants the days to be in displayed in columns (one column per day, not one row per day) and
2. the number of days in a particular month is different.

Therefore, in I add columns with 2 types of templates - one for displaying and one for editing day-related data.

```
private void AddDayColumns(int daysInMonth)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
    {
        TemplateField dayColumn = new TemplateField();

        dayColumn.HeaderText = "" + i;
        dayColumn.EditItemTemplate = new DayEditItemTemplate(i);
        dayColumn.ItemTemplate = new DayItemTemplate(i);

        dailyPlanGrid.Columns.Add(dayColumn);
    }

}
```

**DayEditItemTemplate.cs:**

```
public class DayEditItemTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private readonly int day;

    public DayEditItemTemplate(int aDay)
    {
        day = aDay;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        DropDownList dropDownList = new DropDownList();
        dropDownList.ID = "dayDropDownList"+day;
        dropDownList.Items.Add("item1"); 
        dropDownList.Items.Add("item2");
        dropDownList.Items.Add("item3");
        container.Controls.Add(dropDownList);
    }
}
```

**DayItemTemplate.cs:**

```
public class DayItemTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private readonly int day;

    public DayItemTemplate(int aDay)
    {
        day = aDay;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        Label dayLabel = new Label();
        dayLabel.ID = "dayLabelText"+day;
        dayLabel.Text = "dayLabelText";
        container.Controls.Add(dayLabel);
    }
}
```

**Update 1:** The error has something to do with the fact that I add the day-oriented controls programmatically.

Justification: When I a column in the **.aspx* file, the problem does not occur (with that particular column).

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DayX">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dayXdropDownList" runat="server" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="dayXLabel" Text="dayXLabel" runat="server"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `EditItemTemplate` for each column and bind it as following,

```
<EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="titleLabelEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm doing this already (see line `dayColumn.EditItemTemplate = new DayEditItemTemplate(i);` in my code fragment).